# Free Rails 3 scaffold templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, django-admin

Does anyone know where I might be able to find free scaffold templates (i.e. .css files)? I'm doing a quick and dirty project, and I'm just looking for something generic, but a bit more visually appealing than the extremely generic default. Actually I'd be especially interested in something that look similar to the Django Admin section, but I'm not that picky, really.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this out: https://github.com/pilu/web-app-theme -- it's a basecamp/lighthouse type admin template (including css).
[image: Web App Theme]

It'll work in both rails 2.3 and rails 3 -- the github readme has details.

Comment: Looks quite nice. Thank you. I'll check it out.

Comment: can you install this theme into an existing app?

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Blueprint CSS Framework (http://www.blueprintcss.org/) for stuff like this in the past.